# Can somebody merge my account?

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

I created account

https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/2741/billy

last night, but I want to be bobobobo on that site -- can someone merge my accounts?

(new account:)

https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/2745/bobobobo

Comment: You know that you can change your name for an account once every 30 days?

Comment: Oh I just meant that I wanted it _associated_ with my bobobobo login, this question is not the name specifically, it's about the login id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have high rep on your other SE accounts, the merge has to go through an extra verification step.

It'll happen automatically soon<sup>(TM)</sup>. You don't need to do anything else except maybe ping me if it doesn't happen in a day or so.

(Also, consider using the help form: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge or posting on the site meta next time.)